# Custom URLEncoding for Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am having issues with Alamofire URLEncoding, particularly, for array of parameters where the use [ ] separator for parse the array of parameters.

How can I write my own URLEncoding for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this For **Get**:

```
struct CustomGetEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
        func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
            var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
            request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B%5D=", with: "="))
            return request
        }
    }
```

**How to use**

```
 Alamofire.request("url", method: .get, parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: CustomGetEncoding()).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this string extension

```
 public extension String {
    public func URLEncode() -> String {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
      }
    }
```